# Getting a value from a query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have a URL in this format:

```
http://localhost:57279/AssociateCaseDetails?UId=176948&caseID=1123
```

I need the values of `UId` and `CaseID`:

```
var UId =window.location.href.split("?")[1].split("&")[0].split("=")[1];
```

It’s working, but is there a better way to access the same, given the same URL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of splitting from the `?`, you can use `location.search`. It returns everything from (and including) the `?` until the end of the query string. If there's a hash, it stops right before `#`.

Since it includes the `?`, you can do `location.search.slice(1)` to get the string without the `?`.

Then you can do:

```
var queries = location.search
                      .slice(1)
                      .split('&')
                      .reduce(function(carry, query){
                        var queryPair = query.split('=');
                        carry[queryPair[0]] = queryPair[1];
                        return carry;
                      },{});
```

From `?foo=foovalue&bar=barvalue`, you can get something like:

```
var queries = {
  foo: 'foovalue',
  bar: 'barvalue',
}
```

I have to add that this only works for 1-level query string. Stuff like arrays (`foo[]=foo0&foo[]=foo1`) and key-value pairs (`foo[bar]=bar&foo[baz]=baz`) isn't covered in this logic.